# Retrieving data from a SQL Server database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I am building a website in which I have to retrieve data from a SQL Server database in the format [like](http://www.zomato.com/ncr/restaurants) for different restaurants in the city with their images. Which control should I use in asp.net and how ?

Comment: for database access or for display ?

Comment: A `Repeater` ist the most flexible databound webcontrol.

Comment: or you can use only html,css as well

Answer (score 0):

Use the ListView as it allows you to create clean, cross-browser friendly markup:

[ListView Web Server Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)